# How to upgrade Flutters minSdkVersion without all those errors?

Tags: android, flutter

I already looked at some of the previous solutions where they went in `anodroid/app/build.gradle` and changed the value there. But for me it is just throwing the next error. Here let me show you guys.

```
/home/alex/Schreibtisch/pi_bike_app/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
    uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue] /home/alex/Schreibtisch/pi_bike_app/build/flutter_blue/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pauldemarco.flutterblue" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task :app:processDebugManifest.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue] /home/alex/Schreibtisch/pi_bike_app/build/flutter_blue/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
    Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
        or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
        or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.pauldemarco.flutterblue" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

so this is before changing the version, and this is after :

```
/home/alex/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.0.1.aar/f41c7984a9f414a002350a4d007554b6/res/values/values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

/home/alex/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/core-1.0.1.aar/f41c7984a9f414a002350a4d007554b6/res/values/values.xml:133:5-70: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.

/home/alex/Schreibtisch/pi_bike_app/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:20: error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.
/home/alex/Schreibtisch/pi_bike_app/build/app/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:20: error: resource android:attr/ttcIndex not found.
error: failed linking references.

Failed to execute aapt
com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:796)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.invokeAaptForSplit(ProcessAndroidResources.java:551)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ProcessAndroidResources.doFullTaskAction(ProcessAndroidResources.java:285)
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.IncrementalTask.taskAction(IncrementalTask.java:109)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:173)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:134)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:121)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:122)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:111)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:197)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:107)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:124)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:80)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:105)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:625)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:580)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:482)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.core.AndroidBuilder.processResources(AndroidBuilder.java:794)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.getDoneValue(AbstractFuture.java:503)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:462)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.AbstractFuture$TrustedFuture.get(AbstractFuture.java:79)
    at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.QueueableAapt2.lambda$makeValidatedPackage$1(QueueableAapt2.java:179)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.handleOutput(AaptProcess.java:463)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$NotifierProcessOutput.err(AaptProcess.java:415)
    at com.android.builder.png.AaptProcess$ProcessOutputFacade.err(AaptProcess.java:332)
    at com.android.utils.GrabProcessOutput$1.run(GrabProcessOutput.java:104)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> Failed to execute aapt

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

Now that's weird ain't it? I tried lots of solutions but nothing really does work for me.

Comment: What is your minSdkVersion and compileSdkVersion now?

Comment: @PhucTran its minSdkVersion 16 and upgrading to 19 works well and compileSdkVersion 27. It is just not working when I have flutter_blue installed :/  Issue is here as well https://github.com/pauldemarco/flutter_blue/issues/189

Comment: How is your compileSdkVersion?

Comment: compileSdkVersion is 27 @PhucTran

Comment: Added my answer below. Can you try it?

Comment: @PhucTransurely I will :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Additionally, I'd suggest not to set the minSdkVersion directly but using a slight detour:

```
def safeExtGet(prop, fallback) {
    rootProject.ext.has(prop) ? rootProject.ext.get(prop) : fallback
}
```

and inside your default config:

```
minSdkVersion safeExtGet('minSdkVersion', 19)
```

If you set it directly other libraries may find trouble configuring themselves. I determined that after a good deal to trial and error updating from 16 -> 21

Answer (score 2):

UPDATED (21/02/2019)

2 things:

> 1. Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:flutter_blue]

To fix this, update your minSdkVersion from 16 to 19 (under your android/app/build.gradle)

> **minSdkVersion 19**

---

> 2. Error: resource android:attr/fontVariationSettings not found.

To fix this, we have to use correct compile Sdk version (under your android/app/build.gradle)

> **compileSdkVersion 28**

Comment: Launching lib\main.dart on SM G920F in debug mode...
Note: C:\Users\Pi-Gast\Desktop\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\flutter_blue-0.5.0\android\src\main\java\com\pauldemarco\flutterblue\FlutterBluePlugin.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\Pi-Gast\Desktop\piBike-Lock_Alex\pibikeapp\build\flutter_blue\generated\source\proto\debug\javalite\com\pauldemarco\flutterblue\Protos.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

Answer (score 1):

@Phuc Tran's answer is close, but the Flutter error message tells us the problem -- your library requires a higher Android SDK version than your Flutter project is using. The real solution is to edit build.gradle and change this:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "[YOUR APP ID HERE]"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

... to this ...

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "[YOUR APP ID HERE]"
    minSdkVersion 19   //  <-- *** CHANGE THIS LINE ***
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Comment: This seemed right to me too, but we tried that and it threw another error so we changed the target and compileSdk version too.